# Switching from same-db to separate-db?

Tags: database

I'm using latest drupal 7 and civicrm.

I have an existing drupal/civi install which uses the same database, and i'd like to switch to having separate databases - is that possible?

The civi side is the important part fwiw.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean separating the Drupal and CiviCRM database on an active installation? If possible the easiest would be to re-install with separate databases.

Comment: Yes - it's a long running civicrm installation which has been upgraded to current, but i now want to separate them.. if i installed civicrm fresh with separate databases, what would the transfer process look like? - i assume i can't just copy the civicrm_ tables across?

Comment: This might help: https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/misc/switch-servers/

Comment: hmm ok - from the sound of that i perhaps can do the equivalent of copy the civicrm_ tables (minus a few) - thanks, i'll try following that.

Comment: I ended up following these instructions https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Moving+the+database+using+phpMyAdmin which has some manual elements, and it was successful.

However, i also tried just duplicating the existing combined database (and removing the drupal tables, though that didn't seem critical) then referring to that from a drupal site with fresh standalone civi installed, and haven't noticed any issues.. is there anything i should be aware of doing that?